# BigInteger array with loop. Can't add

Tags: java, arrays, biginteger

```
package fibonacci;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.math.*;
public class fibo {
         public static void main(String[] args) {

             //number of elements to generate in a series
            BigInteger sum;
            BigInteger[] series= new BigInteger[4000000];



           //long[] series = new long[4000000];

             //create first 2 series elements
             series[0] = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
             series[1] = BigInteger.valueOf(2);

             //create the Fibonacci series and store it in an array
             for(int i=2; i < series.length; i++){
                     series[i] = series[i-1].add(series[i-2]);
                     if (series[i].mod(BigInteger.valueOf(2)) == BigInteger.valueOf(0)){
                   sum = sum.add(series[i]);  //error here
                     }

             }
             System.out.println("Fibonacci Series sum " + sum); //error here


             }

    }
```

I am trying to calculate fibonacci's sum of even numbers. What do I need to change here?
Or should the whole program be rewrited using .subtract?

Comment: You don't need to create an array of `BigInteger`, just a variable of type `BigInteger` called `sum`

Comment: Also, don't use `==` with anything other than primitives. Use `.equals()` instead.

Comment: sum = sum.add(series[i]); <- error here. Shows multiple markers. When I write + instead .add it is also not good

Answer (score 7):

initialize `sum`(reference to BigInteger). local variables don't get default values. you have to initialize them yourself.

```
  BigInteger sum= new BigInteger("0");
```

or

```
  BigInteger sum= BigInteger.ZERO;
```

Comment: @Keppil i din't notice the constant in the API. thanks, added it to my answer :)

Comment: `new BigInteger(BigInteger.ZERO);` wont work you have to directly assign `BigInteger.ZERO;`.

Comment: No problem. If you would just get rid of the `new BigInteger()` part around it too I'd be even better.

Answer (score 1):

You need to intialize the `sum` before adding any value in it.

```
BigInteger sum= new BigInteger("0");
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://ideone.com/iCU5pu)**

Hope this helps..

Comment: sum = sum.add(series[i]); <- error here. Shows multiple markers. When I write + instead .add it is also not good

Comment: Working for me... sample http://ideone.com/iCU5pu You need to decrease the size of array it is going out of memory.